# Possible alternative way of expressing continuity of a function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, alternative-proof

In Calculus or Real Analysis the usual form of definition of continuity of a function is $\epsilon- \delta$ def.

From a rigorous point of view, is it possible to say this way? and if so, why?:

$f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (f(x_n))$

Thank you.

Comment: It's Heine definition of limit; Cauchy and Heine are equivalent

Comment: @Michael Galuza: Cauchy def. means $\epsilon- \delta$ def.?

Comment: yes. If I see $\varepsilon$'s (and $\delta$'s), my first thought is "o, Cauchy is out there"

Answer (score 5):

Almost. The second definition is the definition of *sequential continuity*. It is not hard to show that if $f$ is continuous (traditional definition) then it is sequentially continuous.

Using the *Axiom of Choice*, we can prove that if $f$ is sequentially continuous then it is continuous. However, the result cannot be proved without invoking at least a weak form of AC.

Comment: I didn't know about *Axiom of Choice* so in a limit knowledge I read it from wiki. However I don't know it's connection as you've stated. I would appreciate if you please explain it simply for me, and if it is not easy enough don't bother yourself (I know BSc level of maths).

Comment: It turns out there are *lots* of related questions, answers on MSE. Search the site for sequential continuity axiom of choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing a new necessary concept and referring to M.SE so I found some books in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735166/book-books-leading-up-to-the-the-axiom-of-choice), will try reading. :)

Comment: AC is  widely (but not universally) accepted as an axiom of Set Theory. Here is a sketch of sequential continuity implies continuity. Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $a$. Then there is an $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that for every $\delta$ there is an $x\ne a$  such that $|x-a|\lt \delta$ and $|f(x)-f(a)|\ge \epsilon$. Let $\delta=1, 1/2, 1/3$ and so on. For every $1/n$, **choose** an $x_n$ such that $0\lt |x_n-a|\lt \frac{1}{n}$ but $|f(x_n)-f(a)|\ge \epsilon$. (The simultaneous choosing is where AC is used.) We have obtained a sequence $(x_n)$ that violates sequential continuity.

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about the sequential criterion. It says:

> A function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous at $x=a$ if and only if for **every** sequence $a_n\to a$ we have $f(a_n)\to f(a)$.

It is essential the word 'every'. For example, take $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$. Let $a_n=1/(n\pi)$ and $b_n=1/(2n+0.5)\pi$. Both sequences tend to $0$ but $f(a_n)\to 0$ and $f(b_n)\to 1$.

Comment: This counterexample doesn't say that these two def.s are not equivalent. Non-equality occurs in your example because $\epsilon- \delta$ def of continuity is also not applicable for $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: My counterexaple intends to show that if $f(a_n)\to f(a)$ for some sequence, there still can be other sequences for which the condition does not hold, and then the function will not be continuous.

Comment: Yes, another example can be Dirichlet's function (by the sequential 
density of the rationals and irrationals, if we choose irrational point as a limit point of a sequence of rational numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The epsilon and the delta are understood to be numbers. For the epsilon-delta definition to be rigorous, there must be a meaning of the differences f(x)-f(a) and x-a as numbers. For example if there is a metric on the underlying spaces.

In more general cases the definition is: The inverse image of an open set is open,

Since open sets are necessary, the spaces must be topological. Otherwise there is no notion of continuity.